# How to reverse css animation with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I've modified a css hamburger animation to fit my code and now I can't get the css animation to reverse when the second click closes the menu. You can see what is happening here on the website http://schipperbros.com (you will have to resize the browser to 767px in order to have the hamburger icon appear to see what I mentioned above).

Thank you for your help!

```
    <a class="icon"> 
             <button class="c-hamburger ">
                <span>toggle menu</span>
              </button>
     </a>
```

JS

```
function togglescroll () {
  $('body').on('touchstart', function(e){
  if ($('body').hasClass('noscroll')) {
   // e.preventDefault();
  }
 });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
togglescroll()
$(".icon").click(function () {
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".c-hamburger").toggleClass("c-hamburger--htx is-active");
    $("body").toggleClass("noscroll");
    $("body").toggleClass("modal-open");
});
});

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    $(".mobilenav").fadeOut(500);
    $(".c-hamburger").removeClass("c-hamburger--htx is-active");
    $("body").removeClass("noscroll");
}
});
```

Comment: I think your problem is in the CSS. [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618153/looping-a-fade-in-animation/32618980)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just change the second function so it is a

```
.click(fucntion() { ....
```

Remove the if statement and it should work.

**note i'd post this as a comment had i have the rep for it.